# can't edit Instagram client registration

Tags: instagram-api

When I go to Manage Clients in my Instagram developer page I can create a client (i.e. Register a New Client) no problem. What I can't do is change the redirect_uri value. In trying to move from local dev to staging/production I needed to change the redirect uri, but I can't do that in the dashboard without registering a new client. It tells me `Submission error: please fill out all required fields,` even if I put the same exact redirect_uri in that worked previously.

I also get some error text on the Permissions tab: `Company Name, Contact Email and Privacy Policy URL are required to start a submission.` I didn't need any of these fields to register a new client, but I do to edit it? And also, isn't a "submission" when I'm moving from sandbox to production? I'm not trying to move from sandbox yet.

The workaround is to delete the registration and create a new one, but it would be nice just edit it. This method also resets my client secret as well, meaning I have to update my ENV variables.

Thanks,
Gene

Answer (score 1):

After entering your redirect uri, you need to hit tab. If you do it right, the url should turn into a chip:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Manage Clients" -> "Edit" -> "Security" tab

edit your `redirect_uri`

"Update Client"